# jquery comment form validation errorPlacement ajax return

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, response, comments

I am having a problem where my javascript plugins appear to be conflicting, but only slightly. If you look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nick_B/kmJ87/) where I am creating my form, you will notice that after an input field is created, then deleted, the alert messages start popping up on the next element (below where they initially are placed).

To clarify: If the user has not entered any information yet, the alerts pop up in the correct position (floated to the right side of the input field in red text). However, if the user has inputted their name, then deletes their name, the ajax alert ("this field is required") pops up in the wrong place in the field below where it is supposed to.  The problem appeared after I included this part of the javascript (controls a different menu on the page):

```
/* jQuery Content Panel Switcher JS */
var jcps = {};
jcps.fader = function(speed, target, panel) {
    jcps.show(target, panel);
    if (panel == null) {panel = ''};
    $('.switcher' + panel).click(function() {
        var _contentId = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-content';
        var _content = $(_contentId).html();
        if (speed == 0) {
            $(target).html(_content);
        }
        else {    
            $(target).fadeToggle(speed, function(){$(this).html(_content);}).fadeToggle(speed);
        }
    });
};
jcps.slider = function(speed, target, panel) { 
    jcps.show(target, panel);
    if (panel == null) {panel = ''};
    $('.switcher' + panel).click(function() {
        var _contentId = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-content';
        var _content = $(_contentId).html();
        if (speed == 0) {
            $(target).html(_content);
        }
        else {    
            $(target).slideToggle(speed, function(){$(this).html(_content);}).slideToggle(speed);
        }
    });
};
jcps.show = function (target, panel) {
$('.show').each(function() {
    if (panel == null) {
        $(target).append($(this).html() + '<br/>');
    }
    else {
        var trimPanel = panel.replace('.', '');
        if ($(this).hasClass(trimPanel) == true){$(target).append($(this).html() + '<br/>');}
    }
});
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be right about having some css conflicts, but I was able to get close to what I assume is the desired affect by modifying the css on the `label.error` elements.

```
label.error { color: red; position: relative; float: right: top: -30px; }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/kmJ87/1/

Comment: Thank you for your input @shanabus, but still having the same problem that I was having before. Try typing in all of the elements, then deleting one of the fields. The alert message for that field starts coming up on the line below. The problem only happens when a field has been typed in, then deleted

Comment: I understand what you are saying, in Firefox (10.0.2) this does not happen the way you describe. Tripping validation, then deleting a field still retains the error message in the correct area, hovered over the input box floating on the right.  what browser are you using?

Comment: Hi @shanabus. This issue appears on my version of Firefox 10.0.2, as well as Chrome and Safari. I dont know how else to explain this other than: type in all fields correctly, then delete your name. The error message "this field is required" pops up in the email field rather than the name field where it belongs. Modifying the css as you suggested above does not fix the problem for me in Firefox. Thank you for your ideas